# Algebra , a question, concerning a proof. Subrings.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:R \to R'$ be a homomorphism ring $R$ to $R'.$

Prove: If $A$ is a subring of $R$ then $f(A)=\{f(x)| x \in A\} $ is a subring of $R'$

Proof: Just to show closure, that for every $ a_1, a_2 \in A:f(a_1)f(a_2)=f(a_1  a_2)$ I would think to show it's a subring one would have to prove all the attributes concerned with rings ? Am I correct or am not seeing something here ?

Comment: If those are the precise words used, it may well be saying "this is all a trivial check: for example, this is how you check closure under multiplication".

Comment: exactly , this is what they are getting at.. not logical to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $f(A)$ is a subring, you need to show that $f(A) \subset R', x_1 + x_2 \in f(A)$ and $x_1 x_2 \in f(A)$ whenever $x_i \in f(A),$ and finally the ring axioms:

(i)     $(f(A), +)$ is an abelian group;

(ii)    $a(bc) = (ab)c$;

(iii)   $a(b + c) = ab + ac$;

(iv)    $(a + b)c = ac + bc$,

for any $a, b, c \in f(A).$

The first inclusion is trivial, and the rest will follow from the fact that $f$ is a ring homomorphism. Here is the first closure proof as an example: If $b_1, b_2 \in f(A),$ then by definition $b_i = f(a_i)$ for some $a_i \in A.$ Hence $b_1 + b_2 = f(a_1) + f(a_2) = f(a_1 + a_2)$ (since $f$ is a homomorphism). Since $A \subset R$ is a subring then $a_1 + a_2 \in A,$ and by definition $b_1 + b_2 = f(a_1 + a_2) \in f(A).$

Comment: Since it's easy to show $f(A)\subset R'$, isn't it not really necessary to show (ii), (iii), and (iv) on your list because $R'$ is already a ring?

Comment: As @mathers101 say, you don't need to prove all these properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring#Subring_test

Comment: Yup, you're right, all of that follows from the fact $R'$ is a ring. You really just need to show closure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add my own answer because I don't think all the ring axioms need to be shown.

You should show:

$$f(A)\subseteq R'$$
$$f(A)\neq \phi \text{  (clear because $A\leq R$)}$$
$$a,b\in A\implies f(a-b)=f(a)-f(b)\in R'$$
$$a,b\in A\implies f(ab)=f(a)f(b)\in R'$$

to clarify, you don't need to show all the ring axioms because, if you show $f(A)\subseteq R'$, then you know the properties of ring elements apply to elements in $f(A)$ because $R'$ is a ring by assumption. So you just need to show closure.